# What can be diagnosed with a “Application Error Faulting application” event?

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod

Got a BSOD using Windows 10 (CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED) so I checked in event viewer, I'm lost as to what I'm looking at: Faulting `KERNELBASE.dll`? That sounds bad.

```
Event 1000, Application Error
Faulting application name: wmiprvse.exe, version: 10.0.18362.1, time stamp: 0x2b37314e
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.18362.535, time stamp: 0x50cc8d5a
Exception code: 0xe06d7363
Fault offset: 0x000000000003a839
Faulting process id: 0x195c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d5df7649d7129e
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wmiprvse.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: cbd2fe19-56f1-4525-b3ba-92255634e33d
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: Not really clear *what* is being looked for. Restart and hope it doesn’t come back?

Comment: @user2864740 I'm asking what I can do to prevent this, BSODs every other day the last two weeks with the same CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED, System File Checker that's built in found no issues so I can't figure out what could be causing them.

Comment: In that case, try on the general Windows / OS sites. Stack-overflow is tailored to development, not daily OS usage issues. If being a hardcore developer, one could collect and view (fsvo) the dump files. This does not sound like the intent of the post.